# Europe air travel with single entry Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, europe, schengen-visas

I have a single entry Schengen visa. I am traveling from US to Amsterdam with a 2hr layover at Reykjavik. Later I am flying from Amsterdam to Prague with a local easyjet flight. Also I am taking  trains between Prague, Vienna, and Budapest.

Will I face any problem anywhere with my single entry visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're good. Your single entry only gets expired when you leave the Schengen area, not when you move from one Schengen country to another.